# How to format time including milliseconds

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a time string in the format of YYYYMMDD-HHMMSSMilliseconds in Android

Ex: 20130312-1723437520 (2013 March 12th, 17 Hour 23 Minutes 43 Seconds 7520 Milliseconds)

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
String snapshotTime = now.format("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
```

First of all, above code doesn't even work properly. `snapshotTime` is always set to the format string itself.

Second of all, according to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html), there's no way to record milliseconds.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: read the documentation again. (also, that's a lot of milliseconds). tip : try SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class, you can format a Date object into the required format (upper-case S will give millis)

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date now = new Date();
String str = fmt.format(now);
```

That said, using Joda Time is usually a good idea (Proguard will strip code you don't use).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use the strftime formatting, as noted in the Android docs.

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
String snapshotTime = now.format("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S");
```

If you really want to use milliseconds than I would recommend SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the time as unix timestamp with milliseconds from

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

or convert your time to milliseconds:

```
long currentTime = now.toMillis(true);
```

Then you can convert this to your desired date:

```
Time now = new Time();
now.set(currentTime);
String snapshotTime = now.format("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+""+(currentTime%1000);
```

Didn't test it but hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [this](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) little library, it's very helpful when working with dates. Have a look at the DateTimeFormatter class.

As an alternative use Calendar and SimpleDateFormater (you'll have to adjust the format string of course, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for explanation of the symbols)

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-SSSS");
String date = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I only need the above formatting for one occurrence only in the application. I'd like to stick to the Java and Android libraries unless if this is absolutely impossible with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static String format() {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmssSSS");
        Date now = new Date();
        return simpleDateFormat.format(now);
    }
```